# Deezer - Search for tracks, artists, albums with one api call

Tags: deezer

Is it possible to search for tracks, artists and albums at the same time and get something like the deezer homepage search

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do all these searches at the same time, you have to execute multiple requests on each endpoint you need, with the parameters you will find here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/search#connections